# How I can allow free shipping for only specific product in Magento?

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.9

I am working on Magento online store. My client wants to offer free shipping for few products. When I enable free shipping from admin panel system->configuration it enables it for all products as well as it shows other shipping radio boxes also with free shipping. This is wrong. I need when user select product that is with free shipping offer, the customer should get only free shipping option on checkout and other options like ups should be hidden.
Keep in mind that I did not need min. order amount free shipping offer. It should just come with specific products regardless of its price .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default Magento behaviour, if you enable free shipping from admin panel system->configuration , then free shipping will be enabled for all the products.

If you want to enable free shipping for specific products, perform below steps :

- Go to Admin Panel -> Promotion -> Shopping Cart Price Rules

While creating new rule, you required to fill all Rules related fields

**Rule Name:**
 Enter name for your rule. You can set any Name to your rule. It is for internal use only.

**Status:** Set Active to apply rule

**Websites:** Select Websites to where you want to apply rule

**Customer Group:** Select entire Customer Group or those Group you want to apply

**Coupon:** If you want to add coupon then select specified coupon from drop-down (It is not mandatory to add coupon)

**Uses per Coupon:**  It specify the number, that how many times customer can uses per coupon

**From Date, To Date:** It is the time validation of setting rule

**Priority:** Set value 0 or 1 for priority. Lowest priority rule will apply first.

**Public in RSS Feed:** Set yes if you want to distribute your information on-line

**Set Condition:** To set specified condition click on Green plus symbol then select Attribute Combination. After that choose attribute or categories or SKU that you want. You can select more than one condition.

In "Free Shipping" field select **For matching items only** by clicking drop-down

- Save the rule by clicking on "save"
- Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods -> Free Shipping. Set Free Shipping Enabled to "No"
- Save the configuration.

Comment: I did this in same way with free shipping attribute but when i set free shipping to no in Sale -> shipping methods than following error come on shipping method of checkout
"Sorry,  no quotes are available for this order at this time."

Comment: Thanks . it was my mistake . i just missed one point in UPS setting . now all is good and cart price rules are working fine . thanks for such kind answer

Comment: glad it worked for you. You can accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: There is a up & down triangle before the answer, just hit them and you can vote for it. Up Triangle refers to upvote

Comment: Why Set Free Shipping Enabled to "No" though?

Answer (score 0):

in magento 1 if you want to make free shipping for particular product

go to catalog -> manage products -> select product -> prices -> shipping rate -> under shipping rate mark it as '0';
[image]

When you make shipping free then your product looks lke this

[image]